# Orbital mechanisms in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, simulation, orbital-mechanics

it's been a week since I've been trying to create, with the unity engine, an orbital system. I have found different solutions and methods but they don't satisfy the result I would like to see. Can someone tell me how to create a C# script with the addition of other details such as eccentricity?

Here is my "best" and latest code:

## Orbit.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Orbit : MonoBehaviour 
{
   public float axisX;
   public float axisZ;
   public float offsetY;
   public Transform toOrbit;

   public float vel = 0;
   public bool clockwise;


   float _vel = 0;
   float timer = 0;

void Update () {
    _vel = (vel / GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass)*Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    timer += _vel;
    Rotate();
}

void Rotate() {
    if(clockwise) {
        float x = -Mathf.Cos(timer) * axisX;
        float z = Mathf.Sin(timer) * axisZ;
        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(x, offsetY, z);
        transform.position = pos + toOrbit.position;
    } else {
        float x = Mathf.Cos(timer) * axisX;
        float z = Mathf.Sin(timer) * axisZ;
        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(x, offsetY, z);
        transform.position = pos + toOrbit.position;
    }
}
```

}

**PS**: I'm using Unity 5.2

Comment: `Could someone help me to create an orbital system with the use of the laws of physics (including eccentricities, types of orbits etc.)?` Yes, someone could.  If that's not a helpful answer, you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52882227/edit) your question to be more clear about exactly what you are asking.

Comment: What is an "orbital system"? Are you trying to create a solar system? A camera that orbits an object? A satellite orbiting a planet? "Orbital system" is kind of ambiguous...

Comment: @RonBeyer I'm trying to make [orbital mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_mechanics) for my 3d game. I want to know what is the best way to apply them to Unity, using eccentricity etc...I'm using 3D models for my planetray (or solar) system that I've made with 3DS Max.

Comment: If you can express the state of the orbiting body in [ECI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth-centered_inertial) position and velocity vectors, then you can use [these equations and code](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/1919) to calculate features like eccentricity.

Comment: @Ruzihm From this point of view I see it difficult for me, but I can give a try.

Comment: Please, don't call GetComponet every frame. Cache your RigidBody at initialization and use that reference in Update instead.

Comment: If you have [orbital state vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_state_vectors) on `Update()`, you can use [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/8915), and some value of delta time (based on some multiple of `Time.deltaTime`, perhaps) to determine orbital features and then the next position and velocity of the orbiting body after that amount of delta time.

Comment: Thanks @Ruzihm I will check them now!